# Unusual space-filling curve

Tags: gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, space-filling-curves

Around 1998, I encountered a (forgotten) reference to a particularly strange space-filling curve.

Consider a foliation as a collection of continuous nonintersecting curves that start at $(0,0)$ and end at $(1,1)$ and collectively fill the unit square, such as the graphs of functions $f_t(x) = x^t$ where $t \ge 0$.  Supposedly there exists a continuous curve G that starts at $(1,0)$, ends at $(0,1)$, fills the unit square, and crosses each $f_t$ curve only once.

This initially sounds even more impossible than the Cantor curve.  But intuitively a space-filling curve could trace back and forth over the $f_t$ curves and only cross at the corners $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.  Can someone please explain a construction of such a space-filling curve?

Comment: For $n > 0$ take the family of curves `$\{x^a\}_{a \in S(n)}$` in $[0,1]^2$ where `$S(n) := \{n^{-1},(n-1)^{-1},\dots,1,\dots,n-1,n\}$`. The union $\gamma_n$ of these curves can be modified within balls of radius $\epsilon$ about the origin and $(1,1)$ to form a single curve $\gamma_{n,\epsilon}$ from the origin to $(1,1)$. I think (not quite sure) that an appropriate limit gives what you're looking for.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "crossing"? 

Comment: @Steve - The curve $x^{-n}$ only intersects $[0,1]^2$ at the point $(1,1)$.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Not $-n$, but $\tfrac{1}{n}$. Ignore my comment.

Comment: However, a more major concern is that you won't hit anything between, say, $x$ and $x^2$ with that process, so this can't be a space-filling curve.

Comment: Somthing strange here:  if the curve intersects $\{ (t, t^2) \}$
in only one point, it's not filling the square, right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The space filling curve you are looking for does not exist.

Assume by contradiction that such a space filling curve $\gamma:I\rightarrow [0,1]^2$ exists.
Since $\gamma$ intersects each curve $f_t\subset [0,1]^2$ only once, the preimage $\gamma^{-1}(f_t)$ is either a point or an interval. The curve $\gamma$ being space-filling, that preimage can't be a point. It is therefore an interval and, in particular, of positive measure.

Letting $t$ vary,
we have constructed an  uncountable family of disjoint subsets of $[0,1]$, all of whom have positive measure: contradiction!

Comment: Thanks, this is convincing.  But it begs another question.  What was I misremembering?  MathOverflow doesn't have a category for mind-reading questions, but is there an interesting space-filling curve associated with a foliation of the unit square?


Comment: Can't help you.

Comment: This arguement may be true that a "curve" in the sense of a contunuous line or function but what about a "curve" that is a dust as Steve mentioned, a Cantor or Appolonian (Spelling?) set.

Answer (score 8):

André's answer is correct, but what you really are looking for (I think) is [this example](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03024428#page-1), due to Katok, but explained (beautifully) by Milnor.

> There is a family of disjoint smooth real-analytic curves $\Gamma_{\beta}$ that fill the unit square $I^2$, and a subset $E \subset I^2$ of full measure, so that each curve $\Gamma_{\beta}$ intersects $E$ in at most one point.

This means that $E$ can be constructed by choosing one point for each parameter $\beta$, so in order not to contradict Fubini, the dependence of $\Gamma_{\beta}$ on $\beta$ cannot be continuous.